# How to get and use an aspect of a Discord.ui button in it's callback

Tags: discord.py

I am programming a discord.py bot to use the discord.ui buttons, and I would like to use the name of a button to add a string of its label to an already existing string. For example if there is a button with the label "Test", I would want the bot to respond "You clicked on the "test" button", without a specific callback for the test button, and instead a callback that I could add to any button so that the bot always responds "You clicked on the "LABEL" button".

But my implementation includes a loop to create, define, and assign callbacks to the buttons as well

My current code is:

```py
class MyButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, label:string, style:discord.ButtonStyle):
        super().__init__(label=label, style = style)

async def Option_Callback(interaction):
            if(Check(interaction)): #checks to make sure the person clicking the button is the person that called the command
                await interaction.response.edit_message(content=f"You have pressed the {interaction} button",view = None)

button1 = MyButton("Label" discord.buttonstyle.red)
button1.callback = Option_Callback
```

This results in this message being sent:
"You have pressed the <discord.interactions.Interaction object at 0x0000013C0E80B880> button"

**ANSWER**

```py
    class OptionButton(Button):  
            def __init__(self, label:string, style:discord.ButtonStyle):
                super().__init__(label=label, style = style)
            async def callback(self,interaction):
                if(Check(interaction)):#Checks to see if button presser is person that started command
                    await interaction.response.edit_message(content =f"You have clicked on the {self.label} option", view=None)

buttonx = OptionButton("LABEL", style)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating `discord.Button`s you will have to provide 2 different parameters to its "callback" function.

One of these is `discord.Interaction` as you have noticed, the other is `discord.Button`, this is what allows you to access the buttons info.

The easiest way to get this is to just do:

```py
@discord.ui.button(label="Press Me")
async def press_me(interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.Button):
    # I don't remember if it's send or send_message
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"My label is {button.label}")
```

Comment: I know I'm most likely shooting myself in the foot, but I'm not using that method of creating buttons because the number of buttons as well as their label change each time, and I need the label and callback to change each iteration. Currently I'm using a subclass button and predefined callback that I assign to the button that is created as shown above. Is there any way to get the label in that context of not subclassing the view?

Comment: If you subclass it, couldn't you just use `self.label`? Try overriding the callback function instead of using a predefined one so you can access `self`

Comment: Yes, that worked. Creating a seperate button for the options that need the label and assigning the callback within the button class allows it to access self and label